# merge two tables and get sum without select all from huge table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have two user tables with same schema.

```
|  useraward_new   |     |  useraward_his   |
|  User  |  Award  |     |  User  |  Award  |
|  user1 |    5    |     |  user1 |    1    |
|  user2 |    2    |     |  user1 |    3    |
|        |         |     |  user2 |    4    |
|        |         |     |  user3 |    5    |
```

useraward_new contains the data on newest year and useraward_his contains historical data.
The difference is that 'new'.User is unique but 'his'.User isn't so 'his' may contain duplicated user data.

I would like to have

```
|  useraward_total |
|  User  |  Award  |
|  user1 |    9    |
|  user2 |    6    |
```

UNION works fine.
But it returns all data contains in historical table, but only data on users in new table is needed.

I have tried various combination of JOIN, UNION, SUM, ... but no luck.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for answers. The performance of each query has been measured, and both queries of Markus and Tim give good performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT n.[User], n.Award + ISNULL(SUM(h.Award),0) AS Award
FROM useraward_new n
LEFT JOIN useraward_his h ON h.[User] = n.[User]
GROUP BY n.[User], n.Award
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select from the new table and do an inner join on the historical table:

```
SELECT User, SUM(Award)
FROM useraward_new N
INNER JOIN useraward_his H ON N.User = H.User
GROUP BY User
```

edit: I guess that assumes that there is always going to be an equivalent user in the historical table. Otherwise Markus' answer will include any users in new which aren't in the historical table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `EXISTS` to select only users that are in the new table from the history table. Then use `UNION ALL` and `GROUP BY` afterwards:

```
SELECT X.[User], SUM(X.Award) AS Award
FROM(
    SELECT [User], Award FROM useraward_new   
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [User], Award FROM useraward_his h 
    WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM useraward_new n WHERE h.[User] = n.[User]) 
) X
GROUP BY [User]
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c02ff/3/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Unew.User, Unew.Award + Uold.oldAwards
FROM Useraward_new AS Unew
LEFT JOIN
 (
   SELECT User, SUM(Award) as oldAwards
   FROM useraward_his
   GROUP BY User
 ) Uold
ON Unew.User = Uold.User
```

If most Users exist in both tables there's no need to filter before the join, it will be more overhead than aggregating the unneeded rows.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select 
    a.[User], 
    a.Award+(select SUM(b.Award) from useraward_his b where a.[User]=b.[User]) Award
from useraward_new a
```